# Logic of implementing a parallax background where the character can move freely through large level

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I didn't think it was possible to achieve a parallax BG in a side scroller that isn't an auto run, then I saw this on reddit: https://i.redd.it/r1cjvfqerhe11.gif

I'm trying to wrap my head around the basic logic of how the background is "parallaxing" yet still static coming in and out of view as the character moves forward or backward in the level.

I know it has something to do with moving the background layer elements when the player moves, but I can't see the basic logic of what I need to achieve.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That game has 4 layers: sky/clouds, distant hills, front hills, player/platform.  You control the player who moves left or right, when you move the player you move the background layers the same direction but more slowly depending on how distant they are.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, too Much sense if you ask me. Thank you!

Comment: Make your comment an "answer" and ill mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That game has 4 layers: sky/clouds, distant hills, front hills, player/platform. You control the player who moves left or right. When you move the player you move the background layers the opposite direction but more slowly depending on how distant they are.  That is what provides the *3D parallax motion look*.

Comment: Actually the background moves in the opposite direction ;)

Answer (score 2):

Broad question, broad answer:
You would simply take the position of the player, then divide it with a certain (negative) factor and move the background by the result. The bigger the factor, the less does the background move and the farther away it seems.